# Protractor JS - Can't find visible element in a non Angular pop-up

Tags: angularjs, node.js, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I've tried a lot of sou lotion and managed to debug this problem by console logs inside the problematic part of this code, and also using "ignore synchronization" by the book.

All of these doesn't help me to figure this issue out.

The issue starts from the test of ***"Exisiting Client LiveSite - Payments - Perform a payment by PayPal"***

Please your help.

Thanks!

**The code:**

```
 describe('LiveSite Portal - Existing client pay by PayPal', function() {

    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

        beforeEach(function(){
            browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        });

        afterEach(function () {
            browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
        });

        payPalForm = function(){
            browser.driver.sleep(5000);
            element(by.id("login_email")).clear();
            browser.driver.sleep(1000);
            element(by.id("login_email")).sendKeys("username");
            element(by.id("login_password")).sendKeys("password");
            browser.driver.sleep(1000);
            element(by.id("submitLogin")).click();
            browser.driver.sleep(10000);
            element(by.id("submit.x")).click();
            browser.driver.sleep(10000);
        };


    it('LiveSite - Home Page', function() {
       liveSiteHome();
    });

    it('Exisiting Client LiveSite - Payments - Payment form', function () {
        var makePayment = element(by.binding("livesite_actions_texts.pay"));
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(makePayment), 15000);
        makePayment.click();

        var amount = element(by.name("amount"));
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(amount), 15000);
        amount.sendKeys("1");
     });

    it('LiveSite Portal - Exisiting client payments - Welcome note for existing client', function() {
        element(by.name("pay_for")).sendKeys("Mister Bungee");
        element(by.name("notes")).sendKeys("Please approve my payments.\nThanks a lot,\nDr. Kugler.\n+972545453435");
        element(by.name("email")).sendKeys("myemail@email.com");
        element(by.name("first_name")).click();
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.binding("client_zone.client_form.welcome_back"))), 15000);
        expect(element(by.binding("client_zone.client_form.welcome_back")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
    });

    it('Exisiting Client LiveSite - Payments - Continue To Payment', function () {
        element(by.binding("client_zone.payous.new.continue")).click();
        waitPageToLoad();
    });

    it('Exisiting Client LiveSite - Payments - Perform a payment by PayPal', function () {
        var loadLogin = element(by.id("loadLogin"));
         browser.sleep(2000);

        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.binding("buttonText"))), 15000);
        element(by.binding("buttonText")).click();

        if (browser === 'firefox') {
            browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {      
                browser.switchTo().window(handles[handles.length - 1]);
                browser.driver.sleep(10000).then(function(){
                    expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('www.paypal.com');

                     if (loadLogin.isPresent() === true){
                            console.log("-=-=- Login is present - firefox -=-=-");
                            loadLogin.click();
                            payPalForm();
                        } else {
                            console.log("-=-=- Login is not present - firefox -=-=-");
                            payPalForm();
                        }
                });

                browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
                    browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
                });
            });
        }

        else {
            browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {      
                browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
                console.log("Hi I'm in window handle 1 !");
                    browser.driver.sleep(10000).then(function(){
                    expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('www.paypal.com');

                     if (loadLogin.isPresent() === true){
                            console.log("-=-=- Login is present - Chrome -=-=-");
                            loadLogin.click();
                            payPalForm();
                        } else {
                            console.log("-=-=- Login is not present - Chrome -=-=-");
                            payPalForm(); 
                        }
                    });

                browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
                    browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
                });
            });
        };
    });

    it('Existing Client LiveSite - Payments - Payment Succeed', function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
        waitPageToLoad();
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.binding("client_zone.thank_you.show.home"))), 30000);
        expect (element(by.binding("client_zone.thank_you.show.home")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
    });

    it('Exisiting Client LiveSite - Payments - Email has been sent to the business side', function() {
        browser.driver.controlFlow().wait(getLastEmail(), 90000).then(function (email) {
            browser.driver.sleep(3000);
            expect(email.subject).toContain("New payment received");
            console.log('Present the response in the HTML report');
        });
    });

    it('Existing Client LiveSite - Payments - Back to Home Page', function() {
        element(by.xpath("//div[@class='actions']//a[.='Home']")).click();
        waitPageToLoad();
        expect (browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('www.vcita.com/v/');
        browser.sleep(2000);
    });

});
```

**The error:**

```
Failures:

  1) LiveSite Portal - Existing client pay by PayPal Exisiting Client LiveSite -
 Payments - Perform a payment by PayPal
   Message:
     NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.id("login_email")
   Stacktrace:
     NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.id("login_email")
    at new bot.Error (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\
node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113:18)
    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:
706:15
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (C:\Users\idan\
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\
webdriver\promise.js:2464:25)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.
js:563:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.goog.array.forEach (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\array\array.js:203:43)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promi
se.js:552:16)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)
Error
    at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:403:21)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as clear] (C:\Users\idan\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:76:19)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as clear] (C:\Users\idan\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:733:11)
    at payPalForm (c:\automation\tests\payments.js:17:43)
    at c:\automation\tests\payments.js:98:29
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (C:\Users\idan\
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\
webdriver\promise.js:2464:25)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.
js:563:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.goog.array.forEach (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\array\array.js:203:43)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promi
se.js:552:16)
From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async-callback.js:45:37)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Block.execute (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:1174:1
7)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)

    at [object Object]._onTimeout (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2199:18)
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\payments.js:57:5)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21
)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)

    at describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_
modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\payments.js:1:63)

  2) LiveSite Portal - Existing client pay by PayPal Existing Client LiveSite -
Payments - Payment Succeed
   Message:
     Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "angular could no
t be found on the window"
   Stacktrace:
     undefined

  3) LiveSite Portal - Existing client pay by PayPal Exisiting Client LiveSite -
 Payments - Email has been sent to the business side
   Message:
     Error: Timed out waiting for promise to resolve after 90001ms
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Timed out waiting for promise to resolve after 90001ms
    at Error (native)
    at [object Object]._onTimeout (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1591:36)
From: Task: <anonymous wait: promise resolution>
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.wait (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise
.js:1581:17)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\payments.js:117:38)
    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\ja
sminewd\index.js:94:14
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\
Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdrive
r\promise.js:1755:8)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2056:12)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async-callback.js:45:37)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Block.execute (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:1174:1
7)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)

    at [object Object]._onTimeout (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2199:18)
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\payments.js:116:5)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21
)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)

    at describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_
modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\payments.js:1:63)

  4) LiveSite Portal - Existing client pay by PayPal Existing Client LiveSite -
Payments - Back to Home Page
   Message:
     NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.xpath("//div[@class=
'actions']//a[.='Home']")
   Stacktrace:
     NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.xpath("//div[@class=
'actions']//a[.='Home']")
    at new bot.Error (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\
node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113:18)
    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:
706:15
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (C:\Users\idan\
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\
webdriver\promise.js:2464:25)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.
js:563:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.goog.array.forEach (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\array\array.js:203:43)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promi
se.js:552:16)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)
Error
    at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:403:21)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as click] (C:\Users\idan\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:76:19)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as click] (C:\Users\idan\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:733:11)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\payments.js:125:67)
    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\ja
sminewd\index.js:94:14
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\
Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdrive
r\promise.js:1755:8)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2056:12)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async-callback.js:45:37)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Block.execute (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:1174:1
7)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)

    at [object Object]._onTimeout (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2199:18)
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\payments.js:124:5)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21
)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)

    at describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_
modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\payments.js:1:63)

Finished in 130.234 seconds
8 tests, 7 assertions, 4 failures

[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 failed 4 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 4 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1

c:\automation\tests>protractor conf.js
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
imapConnected
LiveSite Portal - Existing client pay by PayPal
  LiveSite - Home Page - pass
  Exisiting Client LiveSite - Payments - Payment form - pass
  LiveSite Portal - Exisiting client payments - Welcome note for existing client
 - pass
  Exisiting Client LiveSite - Payments - Continue To Payment - pass
Hi I'm in window handle 1 !
-=-=- Login is not present - Chrome -=-=-
  Exisiting Client LiveSite - Payments - Perform a payment by PayPal - fail
  Existing Client LiveSite - Payments - Payment Succeed - fail
Waiting for an email...
  Exisiting Client LiveSite - Payments - Email has been sent to the business sid
e - fail

C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-
webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnknownError: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.124)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9
cf),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any sta
cktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.02 seconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'vCitaQA', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arc
h: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEn
abled=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\idan\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6716
_15082}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, vers
ion=43.0.2357.124, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents
=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true,
 browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsE
nabled=true}]
Session ID: 28536d301ca4df393099d6e56ae6c115
    at new bot.Error (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\
node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node
_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\response.js:106:9)

    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\se
lenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:377:20
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (C:\Users\idan\
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\
webdriver\promise.js:2464:25)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.
js:563:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.goog.array.forEach (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\array\array.js:203:43)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promi
se.js:552:16)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1

c:\automation\tests>
```

Comment: The code shown is large and comes with 8 test cases. Could you narrow it down to just the failing bit? The firefox/chrome handling seems irrelevant to the problem you're having. Are all 8 test cases needed to replicate the problem?

Comment: The problem part is "Exisiting Client LiveSite - Payments - Perform a payment by PayPal" , it better to present all thee code in order to understand the flow.